# Select or create from view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, ruby-on-rails-4

In rails is there any simple way to implement select or create from view.

Eg:

```
Product has_many(or has_one) Tags.
```

While creating new Product I can select existing `tags` or create new one.

This can be done by using JavaScript and other ways are there.. But all will take more time and effort.

Please share if you know other simple way...

Edit:

Something like this.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `selector or create from view`? Do you mean you want to perform actual actions from the view itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But imagine you have 100 tags or more ! your page will look bad with 100 checkbox or more..., one elegant way to do this is by using a jQuery plugin called `jQuery Tokeninput` i use it in my project and it's very helpful for what do you want, you can find the plugin [Here](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

This is a screencast on how to use it : [Token fields](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields?view=asciicast)

and this is the revised version : [Token Fields (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised)

check also this blog post about the same plugin if you want too [How to create a token input field where the user can also add new items](http://www.techdarkside.com/how-to-create-a-token-input-field-where-the-user-can-also-add-new-items)

cheer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But there is no option to create new if it is not listed. For that we need another form. That is what I need to avoid. Let me know if I am missing anything...

Comment: noo it's wrong, you can create a new item if it is not listed :)

Comment: i don't remember how to do that, check the link above, if you have access to the revised episode from railscast you will find how

Comment: ): No access.. anyway I will try with this solution

Comment: Implemented it and working fine.. Url in your previous comment is redirecting to somewhere else.

Comment: awesome :) ok i removed it

Answer (score 1):

Yep.

You are after nested forms.  Try, https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

For example,

```
<% form_for @product do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <% f.fields_for :tags do |tag| %>
  <p>
    <%= tag.label :content, "Tag Name" %><br />
    <%= tag.check_box :content %>
  </p>

  <%= tag.link_to_remove "Remove this tag" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= tag.link_to_add "Add new tag" %>

  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Setup the controller and model as given in the documentation and try the above code in the view. This railscast will help you a lot in figuring nested forms http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2